# How to change value of "cell" in dataset?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, dataset

I have a dataset.  I added a column "Tags".  I need to run a function to update the value, for each row one at a time, for the "Tags" column.  Here's what I've tried so far, tell me what I'm missing.

```
public System.Data.DataSet PopulateDataGrid(int nViewMode)
{
  System.Data.DataSet ds = _data.GetGridView(nViewMode)
  ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Tags", typeof(string));

  foreach (System.Data.DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
  {
    dr.BeginEdit();
    dr.ItemArray.SetValue(_dataFactory.GetPartTags(_dataFactory.ExecuteScalar("SELECT POSITION FROM PARTS WHERE PART_ID = " + dr.ItemArray.GetValue(0)).ToString()), dr.ItemArray.Length - 2);
    dr.SetModified();
    dr.EndEdit();
    dr.AcceptChanges();
  }

  ds.AcceptChanges();
  return ds;
}
```

Yeah, I know I could put `using System.Data` and wouldn't have to put it in my code, but this is the only function out of many using that, so I didn't want to do that (if there's no damage to loading time, then I may).  I wish I just needed to run a query and that's it, but this needs to be filled in code.  If someone could help, that'd be great.  Thanks.

**Edit:**  And I've also verified that `_dataFactory.GetPartTags(_dataFactory.ExecuteScalar("SELECT POSITION FROM PARTS WHERE PART_ID = " + dr.ItemArray.GetValue(0)).ToString())` returns the value I want.  It just shows up blank in the DataGridView.  The column is there, but nothing is populated.

Comment: Are you sure it's the function that's causing the problem?  Try substituting a hard coded value for testing and see if it appears in the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just use:

```
dr["Tags"] = _dataFactory.GetPartTags(_dataFactory.ExecuteScalar("SELECT POSITION FROM PARTS WHERE PART_ID = " + dr.ItemArray.GetValue(0)).ToString())
```

You should take note that the `SetModified()` method marks the row as modified, and `AcceptChanges()` clears the Modified/New/Deleted flags. Unless you have underlying code to store that data somewhere or do something more with it automatically, it's a little redundant. Same thing with the `ds.AcceptChanges()`. And if you try to use an adapter later on modified/new rows to push them to the database after you've done an `AcceptChanges()` on the rows/dataset, they won't be found as modified/new/deleted, and the changes won't be pushed to the database.

Comment: lol.  It says you answered 20 seconds ago.  That's about the same time I did that.  :)  Thanks.

Comment: Yep.  I don't know why I was trying to do it so difficult.  I was looking at other code, though "Hmmm, I get information from a dataReader like `dataReader["columnName"]`, why not try that here.  And boom, it worked.  Preciate it.